# How to set widgets at Center vertically on LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set the `Widgets` at `center_vertical` on my `horizontal` `LinearLayout` and set the last `Textview` at right side of parent layout.

I tried it out but I'm having a hard time. I included my code below.

> xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is what I'm trying to produce:

[image]

Comment: So quick question.. the parent view orientation is `horizontal` but you want the child views to be `center_vertical`?

Comment: yes yes i want to keep child views horizentall

Comment: Isn't that somewhat contradicting? Can you provide a ***sample image*** of what you are trying to produce? Try using `Paint`.

Comment: Include it in the post..

Comment: i updated please see once

Comment: I would suggest a RelativeLayout for what you've shown. Why do you think a LinearLayout is good for that?

Comment: then provide solution using relative layout

Comment: Can't. On my phone. I'm sure someone will do it. Or you do it with drag and drop in Android Studio. It's not hard to build a Layout

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_centerVertical` doesn't do anything within a LinearLayout (that's only used in RelativeLayouts)

You'll want to use `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` on the each of the children, or `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on the LinearLayout

**EDIT:** And one way to get your last view to stay on the right side of the layout would be to make your title view have the attribute `android:weight="1"` to make its width expand to fill the layout

Comment: each of children i want

Comment: and i want to set lost textview at right side of parant layout

Comment: @Krish Be clear on the behavior you want. You can edit out your post if you have additions.

Comment: yes i edited my post please give me solution to this

Comment: on your second to last view, you could set `android:weight="1"` to make it expand to take up the rest of the room, pushing the last view to the right

Comment: Or use a RelativeLayout and anchor to the right side... Also, `android:layout_toRightOf` was used, so clearly the layout is supposed to be a RelativeLayout instead

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do what you are trying to accomplish is by using a `RelativeLayout` where `gravity="center_vertical"`. Gonna go ahead and give you the code snippet, since you mentioned you are new to Android.. Maybe next time you'll be the one providing answers. ;)

> sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="Sample Description"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_img" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:text="Hello world"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For more info about `RelativeLayout`s, check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).